# Flash send to back Locked

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs6

[image]

I would like ton know why the arrange options are locked (not clickable). I just started using flash and I have no idea why.

I am trying to send the background to back but I cant click it.

I am using adobe cs6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with individual `Shapes` (made up of vector points, as opposed to pixels) but the point is you do not move vector points/pixels to back or front. Instead you move whole objects to be behind other objects.. To get an object from your shape either convert to symbol (type: Graphic) or do a `Group` or `Union`. The move to back/front option now works.

Now If you made a `graphic` symbol you can always right-click it and "edit" to reshape it (and can exit the edit-mode). If you made a `group` or `union` you can right-click and choose "break apart" to edit but you will have to re-group each time. Graphic symbols is the best option.

**PS:** There are layers too. So draw any background shapes on one layer and do foreground shapes in a layer above that one..

**PPS:** When, if on the same layer, you draw shapes of different colours you can use one colour shape to "cut-away" from the one it overlaps. This isnt a bug its a feature to make more "complex" shapes.